# How to not receive the response from a host

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sockets

In a simple code like this

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(request)
```

I have the need of not having the response from the host to arrive. Is that possible? If yes, how can I do that?

I already tried writing

```
s.close()
```

but the responses arrive

P.S. the host I connect to is a proxy, if it's useful to say.
so even if the response phisically comes from proxy, in reality it is natively generated by the site (not the proxy, the proxy is the intermediate). so i need to not listen the answer, the response of proxy. Just need to send the request

Comment: Perhaps you should connect to an UDP port?

Comment: Why do you care? You are free to ignore the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)` prior to calling `socket.close()`:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown

Comment: can you share exactly what you've run?